# Which should be done first? Domain model or Data Model?

Tags: oop, database-design, model, domain-driven-design

Hi guys let's say I have a new project an inventory system. I will be using Java. I go to my client gather some requirements and after I gather them I will model those requirements. Which should I do first? my class diagrams/domain models? or data model? and why? i would really like you opinion on this. what do you do in the real world in software development?

im using these techs: Java, Hibernate(ORM), Scrum(methodology), postgresql(database)

Comment: The database ERD design should be created first based on an understanding of the application requirements and normalization. The ERD is the *foundation*.

Comment: but dont you think that ERD is for the data storage only? dont you wanna model the problem domain first? what will happen to your operations? behaviors of your objects? maybe you'll miss that out during data modeling. data models are close to domain models except that your behaviors/methods arent there and the entities are for data only. what if your gonna have thinks like sending an email or SMS. what will happen if you are layering?

Comment: No, I don't think that ERD is "for data storage only".  As I said, a proper ERD is the foundation for data-driven application development. OO design methodologies can produce mush if they lose sight of the rules of data normalization.

Comment: thanks for your opinion Tim. will do try doing that on some projects. and also do the opposite. see how that goes. thanks again. =)

Comment: @Tim Data normalization doesn't pertain to ER modeling.  When you switch from an ER model to a relational model, that's when you consider normalization issues.

Comment: @Walter Mitty: The ERD has several "levels" or degrees of specificity: conceptual/abstract, logical, and physical/implementation. At the logical level one does indeed map out whether relationships are one-to-one or one-to-many etc, and one does address the issue of logical primary keys, i.e. which attributes (physically "columns") either in isolation or in combination with other attributes uniquely identify the entity.

Comment: @Tim the Wikipedia article on ER modeling agrees with you.  However, that is not how I learned it.  When I was learning database, ER modeling was at the conceptual level only.  The logical level was called a "relational data model" (assuming the database was to be a relational one).  I don't really know which way Peter Chen had it in his papers on the subject.  I suspect the difference between you and me is more a matter of terminology than a fundamental difference in methodology.  The key thing regarding this question is to separate out conceptual modeling from implementation oriented design.

Comment: @Walter Mitty: A lot of it is terminological. Of the many projects needing rescuing that I've worked on, where the original developers were given the boot, the most frequent causes of the mess have been botched primary key definitions (failure to comprehend which columns together constitute the true PK) and errors of normalization. Developers had started coding the front-end before nailing down the database entities, and when things got messy, they decided the codebase was too far along to be changed.  I would go so far as to say `No front-end coding until the queries are done!` Too radical?

Comment: @Tim maybe they dont have an application architecture(layering) the presentation should only interact with the business logic layer(pure objects: POJOs or POCOs) and the business layer only understands storage interfaces and the data access layer is the one implementing those interfaces so that later you might change your storage from relational to a document oriented db like mongodb.. you can do an IoC on them.

Comment: @Tim ...continuation:  so your presentation layer is storage agnostic and also your business layer.. so yeah.. ur right no front end coding until the queries are done.. queries might mean SQL, object database query library(not using SQL), document oriented database query library(not using SQL). but most importantly your business logic layer must be finished. so I think the parallel on the domain and data models during analysis and design phase is right.. with data models being (ER)... but ER models will be just class diagrams when using object databases like db4o..

Comment: When the back-end is not SQL/relational/normal-form, ontologies can get wild and wooly--totally idiosyncratic--and the model often ends up reflecting one person's arbitrary notions of order. In that case, my answer would be that it doesn't really matter at all where you begin, because it's borderline chaos in every direction :-)

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, if you get the subject matter ontology wrong, you have a snowball's chance in hell of getting the primary keys right.  Of course a lot of people today treat primary keys as a no-brainer:  just give every table an id field, and populate it via autonumber.  No thinking involved!  (irony here, just in case anybody missed it).

Answer (score 3):

My 2 cents...

Data tends to be longer-lived, more stable and ultimately more important than code. So your approach should be data-centric. If you structure and normalize your data properly (and ER diagram is important tool for doing that), the rest will naturally follow.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do either one first.  Create a domain (object) model and an ER model in parallel.  They should be very similar except that the domain model is concerned with data and behavior while the ER model is concerned only with data.

However you need to be very careful to avoid a pitfall that many practitioners, even experts ones, fall into.  That is the confusion between analysis and design.  Both your domain model and your ER model should be analysis models and not design models.  That means that they describe the problem and the requirements, and not the features you are going to add when you design the solution.

In particular, many of the ER diagrams you see in this forum are really relational data models, even though they use ER notation.  And they incorporate design features like foreign keys and don't limit themselves to features that are inherent in the information requirements.

Failure to pin down the requirements fairly precisely before design begins is a major source of failure in large scale projects.  In small scale projects, not so much.

Comment: thanks walter. yes the analysis model part is right. so why not just do the domain model 1st? since it holds both data and behavior. then the data model will be made from the domain model with some adjustments like denormalization..etc so that you'll wont double your work..  what do you think?

Comment: @John Patrick Po: In terms of what comes first, you cannot denormalize what is not yet normalized :-)

Comment: oh.. what I mean is that your domain model might be different from the data model.. say after you do the domain model then make the data model then do some denormalization there.

Comment: Is your domain model an analysis model or a design model?

Comment: its still an analysis model walter.

Comment: Another reason to do them in parallel is based on an iterative methodology. You won't get it right the first time and you need to iterate, see what you have and try at it again.

Comment: OK, as long as it's analysis for both the domain model and the data model, it's probably a good idea to do them in parallel.  Here's where your original question applies:  you should do the logical design of your database before you do the design of the data access layer of the application.  And, borrowing from the iterative methodology, you should be prepared to reiterate the logical database design until the data access layer can come out right.

Comment: If you were designing a database to support multiple applications, life would get a whole lot more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

IMO you should definitely not start thinking about your Data Model first.

The reason is that it's up to your Domain Layer to address all business needs.
Your Domain Layer must be agnostic. It should not be tied to any specific technical implementation nor reference any kind of framework. It should be self contained and work alone. When designing your Domain Layer, do not think about persistence or even the way your data will be displayed. If you need methods to store your data, or methods to gather information from specific UI container like `Session`, just use `Interfaces`.

When designing a Data Model, you're tied to the RDBMS you're going to use to store your data. You will think about the way your schema will be structured to store and access data efficiently. But the thing is that the Business doesn't care about how good your queries will perform.

It's always a good thing to defer critical decisions like the UI, frameworks, database and so on, when you can. That way you focus only on business needs.

Comment: The Domain layer is analysis, right?  As such, you don't "design" it.  You discover it.

Comment: The ER Model is also DBMS agnostic.  In fact, it's agnostic with regard to whether the implementation will be relational or not.

Comment: Thanks for your opinions. your right Walter. you discover it then you design it. but the ER model excludes behavior.. dont you think that you should do the analysis model of the domain 1st using oo(UML) or structured(DFD) approach? including the behaviors (e.g. compute net cost...etc). what do you think?